# Taking a partial screenshot on the iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, screenshot, partial

I'm trying to take a screenshot on save, but can only do full screen. Is there any way to take a partial screenshot?

Here is a sample. Say I just want to take a screenshot of the section highlighted in red. Thanks for the help.

http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/6499/sampleimagez.jpg

Comment: Create a UIImage from the screen and crop it to the size of that view's frame.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/74659-partial-screenshot.html Also, please feel free to choose a username. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @j0k - New accounts that don't choose a username are assigned a number.

Comment: @j0k See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71779/what-is-the-source-of-the-random-user-ids-userxxxx).

Comment: @Moshe Thanks! I couldn't find it when I tried looking for it a while back.

Comment: @j0k - You're welcome. (Let's see if the "move to chat" is triggered while I hit the 15 character minimum quota.)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want a screenshot of that web view there. If you want to get an image of a specific view and only that view (+ subviews), you can use the following code:

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView*)view
{ 
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [view.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Just pass the web view to that function and it should work.

EDIT:

Assuming that was just an example image and you want a screenshot of an area that is not contained in its own view, go with Canada Dev's solution. Crop the image to the area that you want.

Comment: This doesn't seem to capture sub-views of the main view that are not in that view.

Comment: If there are two different views laying over each other, I want to get a screengrab of the intersection of those views (effectively the screen area that is finally visible to the end user).  This code will only take the image from one of those subviews.  I want it to act like the "rubberband" screen shot of the OSX.

Comment: Ah. Then you want a screenshot of the overall view that is then cropped, as Canada Dev said.